# fill in missing values based on available data when merging datasets in R

Tags: r, merge, dataset

Here is my question. I want to merge df1 and df2 datasets.

```
>df1 
ID   Sub  Time Number  Base  Note
01   A01  100  20      20     Y
01   A01  110  35      20     NA
02   A02  100  15      15     Y
02   A02  150  35      15     NA
03   A04  120  10      10     Y
03   A04  130  25      10     NA
04   A05  90   19      19     Y
04   A05  130  50      19     NA
....

>df2
Sub  Time  Number
A01  150   55
A04  200   60
A05  200   80
A02  200   55
....
```

The merged dataset should be like this:

```
>merged
ID   Sub  Time Number  Base  Note
01   A01  100  20      20    Y
01   A01  110  35      20    NA
01   A01  150  55      20    NA
02   A02  100  15      15    Y
02   A02  150  35      15    NA
02   A02  200  55      15    NA
03   A04  120  10      10    Y
03   A04  130  25      10    NA
03   A04  200  60      10    NA
04   A05  90   19      19    Y
04   A05  130  50      19    NA
04   A05  200  80      19    NA
```

If anyone have any solutions for this in R, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `rbind` the two together after adding appropriate columns to `df2`.  Then, after sorting, `na.locf` from package `zoo` will carry the last observation forward.

I cheated here by adding a new level to `df1$Note` to represent original `NA` values in that column, so `na.locf` will carry them forward.

These values can be replaced by `NA` in the result, and the extra factor level dropped.

```
require(zoo)

levels(df1$Note) <- c(levels(df1$Note), 'NA')
df1$Note[is.na(df1$Note)] <- 'NA'

df2$ID <- NA ; df2$Base <- NA; df2$Note <- NA
df <- rbind(df1, df2)
df <- df[order(df$Sub, df$Time, df$Number),]
as.data.frame(lapply(df, na.locf))
##    ID Sub Time Number Base Note
## 1   1 A01  100     20   20    Y
## 2   1 A01  110     35   20   NA
## 3   1 A01  150     55   20   NA
## 4   2 A02  100     15   15    Y
## 5   2 A02  150     35   15   NA
## 6   2 A02  200     55   15   NA
## 7   3 A04  120     10   10    Y
## 8   3 A04  130     25   10   NA
## 9   3 A04  200     60   10   NA
## 10  4 A05   90     19   19    Y
## 11  4 A05  130     50   19   NA
## 12  4 A05  200     80   19   NA
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command rbind.fill from library(plyr):

```
require(plyr)
require(zoo)
merged = rbind.fill(df1, df2)
merged = merged[order(merged$Sub),]
merged$ID = na.locf(merged$ID)
```